# Difference Between "Sell" and "Sale"?

Tags: verbs, differences, nouns, pronunciation

I'm a copy editor at a law firm and need to give a quick-and-dirty explanation of the difference between "sell" and "sale" to a native English speaker (a legal secretary) who is very self-conscious about her grammar knowledge. I've already given her info about how they are different parts of speech, and some example sentences. She's still not comfortable with her understanding but doesn't know or isn't able to articulate the area(s) of difficulty.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Tell your native friend to visit Pittsburgh(my hometown) PA, then Boston, then Atlanta. If she's still self conscious about pronunciation(because that's what this boils down to, not grammar knowledge), then it's time for a career change. Our entire country speaks Slang--not English--even in the most formal settings. Chill out, "it's all good."

Comment: The title should be left alone, k200,000 views confirm  that it is *this* title, in all its simplicity,  which is being sought.

Comment: I rolled back the title to its original because it was more grammatical than it's "improvement"

Answer (score 19):

"Sell" is a verb, an action, it requires conjugation: I sell, you sell, he sells.. I sold, you sold, and so on.
"Sale" is a noun, it is not conjugated and usually would appear together with definite or undefinite article "the sale", "a sale".

When person A sold something, A made a sale.

Comment: "sell" can also be a noun: "a hard sell" and probably many other expressions in the worlds of law and marketing.

Comment: do you have some suggestion on how to disambiguate meanings in this sense?

Comment: maybe if the person is not sure about the use, she should stick to theses uses I pointed out?

Answer (score 6):

`@Tames` is quite right. It's the verb that's the key. And the vowel in the verb.

The **verb** *sell* /sɛl/ contains the mid front **lax** vowel **/ɛ/**, as in **bet** or **men**.

The **noun** *sale* /sel/, derived from the verb *sell*, contains the mid front **tense** vowel **/e/** (also /ey, ei, ej, e:/, etc), as in **bait** or **main**. These vowels are distinctive (i.e, [*Phonemic*](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAPhoneme.htm)) in English.

However, speakers of many languages, like Spanish and Malay, do not easily distinguish [ɛ] from [e], so there may be some cultural problems, since pronunciation is what most people use as memory cues.

If that's not an issue, then the test is

- if it should be *sale*, then you can substitute an equivalent **Noun Phrase** like

  - *the sale that Bill told me about*
- if it should be *sell*, then you can substitute an equivalent **Verb Phrase** like

  - *will sell the remaining stocks*

Comment: Even [some native speakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_l#Fell.E2.80.93fail_merger) pronounce these two vowels the same before /l/, which could lead to their being confused about the grammar (consider how many people confuse *effect* and *affect*).

Comment: People only confuse _affect_ and _effect_ in writing; they're identical in speech, both stressed on the second syllable with a shwa in the first, and nobody cares what the first letter is -- this causes no problem. As for writing, if it's a verb, it's _affect_; and if it's a noun, it's _effect_, in almost all situations. There is a derived noun spelled _affect_ and a derived verb spelled _effect_ that are stressed and distinguished on the first syllable, but they're rare and technical.

Comment: That's what I meant to say; I guess I didn't make myself clear. Somebody (and there are such people) whose speech has *sale* and *sell* as homophones is relatively likely to be confused about them in writing, in the same way that many people are confused about the homophones *affect* and *effect,* or *principle* and *principal*. I find it somewhat difficult to believe that a native speaker is confused about *sell* and *sale* unless they are homophones for her.

Comment: Even if they are homophones, it makes no difference. In speech they cause no more problem than _bear_ (v), _bear_ (n), and _bare_ (adj); i.e, none at all.

Comment: _Effect_ and _affect_ aren't homophones in the [UK](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/effect).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: as a fellow Brit, they are homophones for at least some of us.  Unless I’m hyper-articulating, I don’t think I make any distinction between them in most contexts — the first vowel in both is usually a schwa for me.  (An exception: in the noun sense of *affect*, I stress the first syllable.)  The OED agrees with you, though: it gives the British pronunciation of *affect* as /əˈfɛkt/, and of *effect* as /ᵻˈfɛkt/.

Comment: In American English a few distinguish occasionally between [ɪˈfɛkt] and [ɨˈfɛkt], though I doubt anyone but them realizes it. Everyone **thinks** they always say words the same way -- the way they're spelled (i.e, "correctly"), but in fact centralization of unstressed initial vowels is practically universal in American English, even in the speech of those who may distinguish occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

Sell is transfer possession and ownership of goods or property in exchange for money while sale is the process of selling goods and services.

Comment: Well, it's definitely a quick explanation. But I'm not so certain how useful it is for a person who confuses "sell" with "sale" when writing. Both *sell* and *sale* are about transferring ownership and property.

Comment: Nothing about the difference between the verb and noun forms of the word?